# Continuous several variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I was given conditions such that:

$\ F: R \to R$ is continuous at L, and  $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = L$

I want to verify that I understand these correctly.

I can define $F(a) = b$ and since $F$ is continuous at $L$,  $\lim_{(x) \to (a)} F(x) = L$.

Hence $\forall \space \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $\delta > 0,$ s.t  $\forall \space (x, F(x))$ : $ 0 < |x-a| < \epsilon$, $ \space |F(x) - L | < \epsilon$

And since the limit exists,

$\forall \space \epsilon_1 > 0 $, there exists $\delta_1 > 0,$ s.t  $\forall \space (x, y)$ : $ 0 < |\sqrt( (x -a)^2 + (y-b)^2)| < \epsilon_1 $, $ \space |f(x,y) - L | < \epsilon_1$

In the end, I'm trying to prove $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} F(f(x,y)) = F(L)$. But before I tackle the entire proof, I'm trying to make sure I fully understand what these conditions mean.

Comment: What is the question? A function is continuous at a point in its domain not range. What is the relationship between $F,f$?

Comment: @copper.hat These were the only conditions that my professor gave me; that $F$ is continuous at $L$ and that a limit exists. I edited my post to show what I'm trying to prove eventually, and the relationship between $F$, $f$.

Comment: You have $F(a) = b$ and later $F(a) = L$.